# Having problems with responsive mobile site

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive

I've created the website and checked it in the google developer tools, the site looked great both on my pc and was responding well to a smaller window size.

When I uploaded the site to the host, the site had weird margins to the right on the mobile version.Also, some styles were simply out of place .  I set the  initial scale, as well as used media queries. I'll provide the link to the site below. If anyone can help me , it would be more then appreciated. As someone whose learning on his own , it would be great to hear input from more experienced developers (:

website:http://www.onceuponaneventnj.com/

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  background-color:#EB9AAA;
}
header{
  background-image:url("http://static2.businessinsider.com/image/568d6b65dd0895aa458b46bd-1190-625/bride-outraged-after-the-knot-helps-wedding-venue-bury-negative-review.jpg");
  height:85vh;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
header{
  height:85vh;
  background-size:auto;
  background-attachment:scroll;
}
@media screen and (max-width:754px){
  header{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:left;
    height:82vh;
  }
}

.banner_header{
  display:flex;
  height:100vh;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left:550px;
  width:100%;

}
@media screen and (max-width:1100px){
  .banner_header{
    margin-left:100px;
  }
}
.banner_header_text{
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  font-size:68px;
  color:#EE7E7E;
  animation:banner_animation 3s ease-in;
  max-width:100%;
  margin-left:-70px;
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
  .banner_header_text{
    display:none;
  }
}
@keyframes banner_animation{
  from{opacity:0}to{opacity:1}
}
#stars{
  opacity:.60;

}
.logo h1{
  font-size:34px;
  color:white;
  margin-right:100px;
  margin-top:15px;
  font-family: cursive,sans-serif;
}
.logo h1 a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:white;
  letter-spacing:1px;
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
  .logo h1{

    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;!important;
    align-items: center;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    padding-top:5px;
    font-size:25px;
    font-family:'tangerine',cursive,sans-serif;

  }
  header{
    height:85vh;
  }
}
/*-------------MAIN NAVIGATION---------------------------*/
.main-navigation{
  display:flex;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:#EE7E7E;
  width: 100%;
  height:70px;
  justify-content: center;
}
.main-navigation ul{
  display:inline-flex;
}
.main-navigation ul li{
  font-size:20px;
  z-index:1;
  list-style:none;
  padding-top:10px;
}
.main-navigation ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  padding:15px;
  font-family:'Lato',sans-serif;
}
.main-navigation ul li a:hover{
  opacity:.20;
}
nav ul li:hover .menu_services_child{
  display:flex;
}
nav ul li:hover>.menu_services_child a{
  color:#f45050;
}
.menu_services_child{
  display:none;
  height:500px;
  flex-direction:column;
  position:absolute;
  padding-top:15px;
  color:#F45050;
  margin-left:10px;
  font-size:18px;
}
label{
  margin-left:20px;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  font-size:32px;
  line-height:70px;
  display:none;

}
#toggle{
  display:none;
}
@media screen and (max-width:667px){
label{
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
  nav{
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .main-navigation{
    width:100%;
    font-size:15px;
    height:80px;
  }
  .main-navigation ul li{
    padding-top:0;
  }

nav ul{
  display:block;
  margin-top:80px;
  margin-right:-30px;
}
nav ul li{
display:block;
}

.main-navigation ul {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left:-405px;

  }
  .main-navigation ul li a{
    font-size:16px;
    text-align:center;
    color:black;
    font-family:cursive,sans-serif;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:pink;
    width:100%;
  }
  .main-navigation .menu_services_child a{
    font-size:12px;

  }
  .menu_services_child{
    height:210px;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:0;
  }

  nav ul li:hover .menu_services_child {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    font-size:15px;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    font-size:2px;
    padding-top:5px;
  }
input[type=checkbox]:checked~nav{
  visibility: visible;
}


}


/*-----------------------------------------------------
-----------------------AFTER HEADER , PINK BOX--------*/
.first_container{
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#E48C8C;
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
  .first_container{
    height:120px;
    line-height:40px;;
  }
}
.pt_one{
  padding:10px;
  letter-spacing:3px;
}
.main_tag_one{
  font-size:35px;
  margin-bottom:12px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  color:#EEE9E9;
  font-family: 'tangerine', cursive;
}
.underline_firstcontainer{
  border-top:1px solid #CA7474;
  width:10%;
  height:1px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-left:120px;
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
  .main_tag_one{
    display:none;
  }
}
.main_tag_two{
  font-size:25px;
  margin-top:50px;
  color:#FFC0C0;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Bubbler One', sans-serif;
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
  .main_tag_two{
    font-size:20px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:1px;
    color:#FCEAEA;
  }
}

/*---------------------
-----------------------------BOXES----------------------------*/
.second_container{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  height:400px;
  background-color:white;
  color:white;
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
  .second_container{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
  }
}
.box{
  background-color:#444;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:150%;
}
.box-a {
  background-image:url('images/wedding2.png');
  background-position:center;
  background-size:cover;
  filter:grayscale(70%);
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
.box-a a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:white;
}
#weddings{
  font-size:50px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height:100%;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;

}
.box-a:hover{
  filter:grayscale(0);
}
.box-b{
  background-image:url('images/social1.jpg');
  background-position:center;
  background-size:cover;
  overflow:hidden;
  filter:grayscale(70%);
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
.box-b a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:white;
}
.box-b:hover{
  filter:grayscale(0);
}
#social{
  font-size:50px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height:100%;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
}
.box-c{
  background-image:url('images/corporate1.jpg');
  background-position:center;
  background-size:cover;
  filter:grayscale(70%);
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
.box-c a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:white;
}
.box-c:hover{
  filter:grayscale(0);
}
#corporate{
  font-size:50px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height:100%;
  align-items:center;
  font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
}
.box-d{
  background-image:url('images/island.jpg');
  background-position:center;
  background-size:cover;
  filter:grayscale(70%);
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
.box-d a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:white;
}
.box-d:hover{
  filter:grayscale(0);
}
.box-d_content{
  color:white;
  height:100%;
  font-size:50px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height:100%;
  align-items:center;
  font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
  .box-a{
    height:200px;
  }
  .box-b{
    height:200px;
  }
  .box-c{
    height:200px;
  }
  .box-d{
    height:200px;
  }
}
/*-------------------------------ABOUT SARA PAGE HOME------------------------
---------------------------------*/
.our_story{
  display:block;
  height:500px;
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom:250px;
}
.our_story img{
  width:267px;
  height:400px;
  border-radius:20px;
  margin-left:-100px;
  position:absolute;
}
.our_story_title{
  padding-top:15px;
  font-size:25px;
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
}
#our_story_underline{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:120px;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
}
.our_story_subheader{
  font-size:14px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family:cursive, sans-serif;
}
.our_story_title{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
#walt{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top:-10px;
  font-size:16px;
  width:100%;
  font-family: cursive, sans-serif;
}
.our_story_text {
  font-size:18px;
  display:inline-flex;
  line-height: 30px;
  height:100%;
  width:60%;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Bubbler One', sans-serif;
  padding-left:100px;
  padding-right:20px;
  margin-right:100px;
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
.our_story{
  display:block;
  margin-top:400px;
  font-size:10px;
  height:900px;
  }
  #walt{
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:center;
  }
  .our_story_text{
    font-size:14px;
    width:80%;
    padding-left:50px;
    margin-right:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
    line-height:20px;
  }
  .our_story img{
    height:350px;
    margin-top:-400px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:754px){
.our_story{
  display:block;
  margin-top:400px;
  font-size:10px;
  height:900px;
  }
  #walt{
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:center;
  }
  .our_story_text{
    font-size:14px;
    width:80%;
    padding-left:50px;
    margin-right:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
    line-height:20px;
  }
  .our_story img{
    height:350px;
    margin-top:-400px;
    margin-left:60px;
  }
}
.footer_wrapper{
  height:300px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#E35B5B;
}
.footer_nav{
  display:inline-flex;
  width:100%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top:50px;
}
.footer_nav li{
  list-style:none;
}
.footer_nav li a{
  font-size:40px;
  color:#EE7E7E;
  padding:20px;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-family: 'Bubbler One', sans-serif;
}
.footer_nav li a:hover{
  color:white;
}
.footer_icons ul{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  list-style: none;
  color:white;
  margin-top:-10px;
}
.footer_icons ul li{
  font-size:40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background:#CA7474;
  border-radius:100px;
  margin:10px;
}
.footer_icons ul li a{
  padding:18px;
  color:#F3C7C7;
}
.footer_icons ul .facebook:hover{
  background:#3b5998;
  opacity:.88;
}
.footer_icons ul .instagram:hover{
  background:#9b6954;
  opacity:.88;
}
.footer_icons ul .linkedin:hover{
  background:#0077B5;
  opacity:.88;
}
#email{
  display:flex;
  font-size:16px;
  justify-content: center;
  width:100%;
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-top:-20px;
  font-family:'lato';
}
#email a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#EE7E7E;
}
#email a:hover{
  color:#FFEDED;
}
.footer_cellphone{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top:10px;
  font-size:16px;
  margin-left:50px;
  color:#EE7E7E;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family:'museo_sans300';
  width:100%;
}
.footer_cellphone:hover{
  color:#FFEDED;
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
  .footer_wrapper{
    height:300px;
  }
  .footer_nav li a{
    font-size:30px;
    padding:10px;
  }
  .footer_nav{
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:-45px;
  }
  .footer_icons{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left:-50px;
  }
  .footer_icons ul li{
    font-size:20px;
  }
  #email{
    width:200px;
    margin:-20px auto auto auto;
  }
  .footer_cellphone{
    width:200px;
    margin:10px auto auto auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script|Lato|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bubbler+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coming+Soon" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c270b3bf59.js"></script>
    <title>Once Upon An Event</title>
  </head>



<header>
  <div class="main-navigation">
    <div class="logo">
      <h1><a href="index.html">Once Upon An Event</a></h1>
    </div>
    <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"</input>
      <nav>
        <ul id="menu_services">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Services</a>
                <div class="menu_services_child">
                  <a href="weddings.html">Weddings</a>
                  <a href="Social.html">Social</a>
                  <a href="corporate.html">Corporate</a>
                  <a href="vacation.html">Vacation</a>
                </div>
            </li>
              <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

    </div>
    <div class="banner_header">
      <div class="banner_header_text">
        <h1>Making Dreams A Reality...</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
</header>

<body>
  <div class="first_container">
    <div class="pt_one">
      <div class="main_tag_one"><h2>Once Upon An Event</h2><div class="underline_firstcontainer"></div></div>
      <div class="main_tag_two"><h3>Planning the Event you've Always Dreamed Of</h3></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="second_container">
        <div class="box-a"><a href="weddings.html"><div id="weddings">Weddings</div></a></div>
        <div class="box-b"><a href="social.html"><div id="social">Social</div></a></div>
        <div class="box-c"><a href="corporate.html"><div id="corporate">Corporate</div></a></div>
        <div class="box-d"><a href="Vacation.html"><div class="box-d_content">Vacation</div></a>
        </div>
  </div>
<div class="our_story">
  <div class="our_story_title">
    <div id="our_story_underline"></div>
    <h1>Sara Ray</h1></div>
    <div class="our_story_subheader"><h2>Founder &amp; CEO</h2></div>
      <div id="walt">  <h3><b>”All our dreams can come true, if we have the courage to pursue them.” ~ Walt Disney</b></h3></div>
          <div class="our_story_text"><p>     A graduate from the State University of New York at New Paltz, Sara began her career by

working for The SYNERGY Events. She helped coordinate the Emerging Trends Fashion Show which took place during both New

York and Boston's Fashion Week. Her main duties included booking various vendors like

photographers, entertainment, hairstylists/MUA as well as making the event run as smoothly as

possible.   In addition, she worked for Todd &amp; Jayde in the Morning on WPLJ 95.5 where she

assisted with multiple tasks in a fast-paced environment .<br><br>

     Lastly, Sara worked for the Madison Square Garden Company with the Communications team

for the New York Rangers. Within that time frame, she helped plan and organize on and off-ice

events and setting up the media area prior to every hockey game .<br><br>

     All of these skills Sara has aquired throughout these experiences have given her a chance

to grow and become more knowledgable in the field. This is why she came to the decision

to open up Once Upon An Event, LLC. OUAE will focus on every client's individual needs and wants, guranteeing their event is as magical as they imagined.

OUAE can be the key component to making a client’s

dreams, a reality..</p>
      </div>
          <img src="images/saraabout.jpg"width="500px" height="800px">


</div>
</body>
<footer>
  <div class="footer_wrapper">

      <ul class="footer_nav">
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="weddings.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

      </ul>

    <div class="footer_icons">
    <ul>
      <li class="facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/onceuponaneventnj/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></a></i></li>
      <li class="instagram"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/onceuponanevent_/"target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></a></i></li>
      <li class="linkedin"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/sararayrozycki/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></a></i></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
      <div id="email"><a href="mailto:onceuponaneventservices@gmail.com">OnceUponAnEventServices@gmail.com</a></div>
        <div class="footer_cellphone">Contact Us: 201-456-6773</div>

  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Please add your codes so that you could get help on issue related to responsive layout. Add media query at different break-points.

Comment: Does seem to me that mobile width in a desktop browser doesn't have the problem, but I do see it on my actual phone. You might try hooking your phone up to your computer to debug that way. See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/ for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You've pasted far too much code in here, whilst you can't expect someone to go through it all and fix it.

I can advise you that in the Chrome Developer Tools (or most popular browser's dev Tools) there is an option to scale the browser down to mobile sizes for popular phones.

If you choose one of these presets you can then look into your dev tools to see what has gone wrong, look at and adjust the properties to see what they should be at this size. Perhaps then you may need to add some extra media queries.

Don't be phased, it is rare you're going to have 1 nice rule that will scale everything nicely at every size. Often multiple media queries are necessary.

Good luck!